# Visual Studio 2022: Impossible to install a VSIX extension from 'Analyzer with Code Fix (.NET Standard)' project template

Tags: project, rules, vsix, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm currently trying to create a new code analysis rule for Visual Studio 2022 so i followed this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix).

When you follow the tutorial, you have to create a new Analyzer with Code Fix (.NET Standard) project that will in fact create 5 projects into your new solution (Rule definition/Code fixes/Package/Testing/VSIX).

I succeeded to create my code analysis rule and i can test it when i start debugging the VSIX project. It opens a second instance of Visual Studio and i can write some code and see if my rules are applied...

However i'm not able to install it on my own Visual Studio through the VSIX extension file. I have the following error when i try to install it :

```
04/01/2024 15:05:56 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
04/01/2024 15:05:56 - -------------------------------------------
04/01/2024 15:05:56 - vsixinstaller.exe version:
04/01/2024 15:05:56 - 17.8.2365+1ea9c98024
04/01/2024 15:05:56 - -------------------------------------------
04/01/2024 15:05:56 - Command line parameters:
04/01/2024 15:05:56 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\VSIXInstaller.exe,D:\ProjectNET\Rules\SDNARules\NETStandardByRefRules.Vsix\bin\Debug\net481\NETStandardByRefRules.Vsix.vsix
04/01/2024 15:05:56 - -------------------------------------------
04/01/2024 15:05:56 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
04/01/2024 15:05:56 - -------------------------------------------
04/01/2024 15:05:56 - Initializing Install...
04/01/2024 15:05:56 - Searching for applicable products...
04/01/2024 15:05:57 - Found installed product - Visual Studio Enterprise 2022
04/01/2024 15:05:57 - Found installed product - Global Location
04/01/2024 15:05:57 - Extension Details...
04/01/2024 15:05:57 -   Identifier         : SDNACodeAnalysisRules.Silicon DNA 1994..47352a77-3f81-4d95-a389-a64702e17c53
04/01/2024 15:05:57 -   Name               : SDNARules
04/01/2024 15:05:57 -   Author             : ALP
04/01/2024 15:05:57 -   Version            : 1.0
04/01/2024 15:05:57 -   Description        : This is a sample diagnostic extension for the .NET Compiler Platform ("Roslyn").
04/01/2024 15:05:57 -   Locale             : en-US
04/01/2024 15:05:57 -   MoreInfoURL        : 
04/01/2024 15:05:57 -   InstalledByMSI     : False
04/01/2024 15:05:57 -   SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.5,)
04/01/2024 15:05:57 -   SignatureState     : Unsigned
04/01/2024 15:05:57 -   Supported Products : 
04/01/2024 15:05:57 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
04/01/2024 15:05:57 -           Version : [15.0,)
04/01/2024 15:05:57 -           ProductArchitecture : x86
04/01/2024 15:05:57 -   References         : 
04/01/2024 15:05:57 -   Prerequisites      : 
04/01/2024 15:05:57 -       -------------------------------------------------------
04/01/2024 15:05:57 -       Identifier   : MyCustomPrerequisite
04/01/2024 15:05:57 -       Name         : My Custom Prerequisite
04/01/2024 15:05:57 -       Version      : [1.0,)
04/01/2024 15:05:57 - Signature Details...
04/01/2024 15:05:57 -   Extension is not signed.
04/01/2024 15:05:57 - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableDataImpl(String vsixPath, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.IsExtensionPack(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.ExpandExtensionPackToInstall(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

And here is my source.extension.vsixmanifest file in the VSIX project :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PackageManifest Version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2011" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema-design/2011">
  <Metadata>
    <Identity Id="SDNACodeAnalysisRules.Silicon DNA 1994..47352a77-3f81-4d95-a389-a64702e17c53" Version="1.0" Language="en-US" Publisher="ALP"/>
    <DisplayName>SDNARules</DisplayName>
    <Description xml:space="preserve">This is a sample diagnostic extension for the .NET Compiler Platform ("Roslyn").</Description>
  </Metadata>
  <Installation>
    <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" Version="[15.0,)" />
  </Installation>
  <Dependencies>
    <Dependency Id="Microsoft.Framework.NDP" DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework" d:Source="Manual" Version="[4.5,)" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Assets>
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.MefComponent" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="SDNARules" Path="|SDNARules|"/>
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Analyzer" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="SDNARules" Path="|SDNARules|"/>
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.MefComponent" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="SDNARules.CodeFixes" Path="|SDNARules.CodeFixes|"/>
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Analyzer" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="SDNARules.CodeFixes" Path="|SDNARules.CodeFixes|"/>
  </Assets>
  <Prerequisites>
      <Prerequisite Id="MyCustomPrerequisite" Version="[1.0,)" DisplayName="My Custom Prerequisite" />
  </Prerequisites>
</PackageManifest>
```

Here is an image :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0b2Im.png)

I can provide my code if you want but i tested with a new created project and this is the same result so i don't think that my rule is the problem.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried to target framework 4.7.2 and 4.8, set the architecture of the projects to x64, to install the Nuget package through the .nupkg file, i have created my own prerequisites in the VSIXManifest file, etc

Answer (score 0):

According to your posting of manifest file, you are using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community as installation target id.

But according to this: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/vsix-extension-schema-2-0-reference?view=vs-2022#:~:text=default%20value%20%22ProductExtension%22%3A-,Id,-%2D%20This%20attribute%20identifies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/vsix-extension-schema-2-0-reference?view=vs-2022#:%7E:text=default%20value%20%22ProductExtension%22%3A-,Id,-%2D%20This%20attribute%20identifies), that value seems not to be valid.

I would try to change the installation target id to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro

Comment: @Yunnosch, edited the answer to a suggestion based on Microsoft Learn reference.

Answer (score 0):

From your log we can see that in the manifest you are targeting 'Product Architecture' of 'x86'.  However, Visual Studio 2022 is 64-bit, which means [you need 'amd64' in here or things won't work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67769432/error-vssdk1311-about-productarchitecture-when-building-extension-for-vs2022)

You can change it using the manifest editor in Visual Studio, the one that appears if you doubleclick the .vsixmanifest file in Solution Explorer.  The setting is under the Install Targets tab, hit 'Edit' with Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community selected and 'amd64' is in the dropdown for Product Architecture on the screen that appears.

I get a similar error with my own extensions if I change the setting to x86 and try to install a built version in Visual Studio 2022.  However, they don't run successfully in the Experimental Instance (i.e. from debug) either, and you are saying yours do, so maybe there's some other issue.